# If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of A then p($\lambda$) is eigenvalue of p(A) - lemma wrong?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a Matrix and $p\in \Pi_m (\mathbb{R})$. (no further described what $m$ is)

Proof: If $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$ too.

In my opinion this is not true, e.g. choose $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\-1&2&1\\3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $p(\lambda) = 3\lambda ^2 +5\lambda - 7$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{0,-2,2\}$ and the eigenvalues of $p(A) = 3A^2 +5A-7I = \begin{pmatrix}22&46&39\\-5&15&5\\27&46&34\end{pmatrix}$ are $\{-5,15,61\}$. 
But $p(0) = -7$ which is not in $\{-5,15,61\}$.

Am I missing something or is this statement indeed false?

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A$ are $4$ and $\pm 2$.

Comment: You're right. Then my concerns are irrelevant. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Octave or Matlab(if you have a license). They can do matrix calculations pretty easily and without mistakes, so you can always double check your work. Really helpful :D